# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Issue when stroking path

Tags: iphone, xcode, path, uibezierpath, stroke

I've been getting a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error while drawing, filling and then stroking a path. Here is the code:

```
UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

[aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 88)];
[aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(interPoint, 0)];
[aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(interPoint, 176)];
[aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 88)];

[aPath closePath];

[[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
[[UIColor colorWithHue:0.1583 saturation:1 brightness:1 alpha:1.0] setFill];

aPath.lineWidth = 1;

[aPath fill];
[aPath stroke];
```

The error seems to be happening when the program gets to `[aPath stroke]`. If I comment out `[aPath stroke]` the error goes away. I know that an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error has to do with memory management, but I can't figure out where the problem is. Any help would be great.

Comment: What happens if you comment out `aPath.lineWidth = 1;`?

Comment: That does not help, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

To figure out Why and Where is the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error is follow following step :

In Xcode Go to **Product** -> **Scheme** -> **Edit Scheme**
A screen will pop up. In that select Argument tab. Under that go to Environment Variable section and click on add button to add attribute with Name NSZombieEnable with Value YES.

Now  run your app.
It will provide you detail log for you EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

You can increase the variable retain count before it gets deallocated in the memory using **[variableName retain];**

In your case use **[aPath retain];** before aPath is getting deallocated.